# JAVA FX - TimeLine Animation (Find certain x,y point during animation)

Tags: java, javafx

In this program, I am trying to make rect turn red when x== 600 in the for-loop. What basically happens is that the for-loop runs faster than the animation on the screen. The rectangle ends up turning red before it actually hits that certain point within the JavaFX screen.

What I would like it to do it that when it hits point x,y:(600,500), make the blue rectangle turn red.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class TestPoint extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle();

        //Obstacle that other square must hit
        rectTwo.setWidth(100);
        rectTwo.setHeight(100);
        rectTwo.setX(500);
        rectTwo.setY(500);
        rectTwo.setFill(Color.PINK);

        //for loop that causes the animation to properly move
        for (int x = 800; x >= 0; x--) {
            rect.setWidth(100);
            rect.setHeight(100);
            rect.setX(800);
            rect.setY(500);
            rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
            timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
            final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(rect.xProperty(), x);
            final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(8), kv);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
            timeline.play();
            //if it hits the point of rectTwo, change to Color.RED
            System.out.println(x);
            if (x == 600) {
                rect.setFill(Color.RED);
                break;//end 
            }
        }

        root.getChildren().addAll(rect, rectTwo);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstood, how `Timeline` works. Your code creates 201 `Timeline` animations running in parallel. The loop is done ***before the window is shown***. Any updates are automatically triggered by JavaFX later.

Specifying the initial state and the target state via `KeyFrame`s is sufficient. `KeyFrame`s allow you to specify a handler to be executed at a specific time; this can be used to change the color. Alternatively the `onFinished` handler could be used for coloring the `Rectangle`.

```
rect.setWidth(100);
rect.setHeight(100);
rect.setY(500);
rect.setFill(Color.BLUE);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(rect.xProperty(), 800)),
        new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(8),
                evt -> rect.setFill(Color.RED),
                new KeyValue(rect.xProperty(), 600)));
timeline.play();
```

Comment: Can I use a collision detector too, like BooleanBinding or is this method better?

Comment: For collision detection you could trigger stepwise updates using a single `KeyFrame` with an event handler with a small duration to do an "update loop" which allows you to do the collision checks after the updates are done, you could use a seperate `AnimationTimer` or you could register a listener to the `x` property of the rect...The listener approach is the most likely to repeat checks, if you create more complex animations.

Comment: How would I go on about with creating the listener to the x property of the rectangle? Any tutorials I can watch?

Comment: Just check out the `addListener` methods: [`ObservableValue`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html#addListener%28javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener%29) and [`Observable`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/Observable.html#addListener%28javafx.beans.InvalidationListener%29). Shouldn't be too hard to implement one of those interfaces even without doing a tutorial. Example: `rect.xProperty().addListener(o -> { ... });`